# Material table sort courses type error when called onInit

Tags: angular, typeerror, angular-material-table

I have a observable that i called on init. I also assign `sort` and `pagnation` to the datasource. Everythin seems to work. But I get an error.

Code

```js
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.dataejers);

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator:any= MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort:any= MatSort;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.stateService.startupData.subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.dataejers = data.dataejers;
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.dataejers);
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    })
  }
```

Error:

```
ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, ReadableStream, Array, AsyncIterable, or Iterable
```

Comment: What's the format of the this.dataejers?

Comment: @Ardit. It an array.

Comment: You can Replace: dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.dataejers); ---> dataSource: Observable<any[]>;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.First change:

```
dataSource:MatTableDataSource<dataejers> = new MatTableDataSource<dataejers>();
```

You are passing an undefined object to MatTableDataSource.

2.Remove from ngOnInit (from the doc):

```
this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
```

3.Dont create a new MatTableDataSource:

```
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.dataejers);
```

Assign data like this

```
this.dataSource.data = data.dataejers;
```

Comment: remove from `ngAfterViewInit()`

Comment: No, from ngOnInit

Comment: If I do that the code breaks. `Type 'MatTableDataSource<dataejers>' is not assignable to type 'MatTableDataSource<unknown>'`

Comment: Updated response

Comment: If I remove `this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;` and t`his.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;`  from ngOnInit sort and pagnation stops working.

Comment: @Ardit, each time you create a MatDataSource (and in subscribe Rud have: `this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.dataejers);`) the dataSource.sort and dataSource.paginator becomes "null".

Comment: Updated response